# linearly independent elements of W

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

I want to ask about the number of linearly independant elements of

$W=(u_{1},u_{2},...,u_{m},u_{1}-u_{2},u_{2}-u_{3},...,u_{m-1}-u_{m},u_{m}-u_{1})$.

I say that it is $m$ and i need someone to confirm or not that.

Thanks

Comment: Are $u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_m$ linearly independent?

Comment: Can you tell us why you think it is $m-1$?

Comment: @velutluna yes . I just correct my proposition, i think it is m and not m-1 because  i can construct $u_{i}-u_{i+1}$ with taking the sum of all the other $u_{i}-u_{i+1}$ so i delete one of them and let just one $u_{i}$, because with two $u_{i}$ or more i can construct $u_{i}-u_{i+1}$

Comment: It's at most $m$. It could be as little as zero, if $u_1=\cdots=u_m=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the number of linearly independent vectors among $u_1, \ldots, u_m$.

Notice that $$\operatorname{span}\{u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_m, u_1 - u_2, u_2 -
 u_3, \ldots, u_{m-1} - u_m, u_m - u_1\} = \operatorname{span}\{u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_m\}$$

because all $u_i - u_{i+1}$ are linear combinations of $u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_m$.

Thus, the number of linearly independent vectors in $W$ is equal to the number of linearly independent vectors in $\{u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_m\}$.

In particular, assuming $u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_m$ are linearly independent, the number or linearly independent vectors in $W$ is $m$.

Comment: In a paper they talk about to form "padded subset" of W. Do you have any idea about what does it mean ?

Comment: @nour I have no idea. Perhaps it is something like this: If you have $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then you could pad it with zeroes to obtain $(x_1, \ldots, x_n, 0, \ldots, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ for some $m > n$. If a set was linearly independent, then the padded set will also be linearly independent.

Comment: I have found that each  vectoris a linear combination of this set. For example $(u_{1}-u_{2},...u_{m-1}-u_{m})$ is a padded subset of W. What interests me it's how much i can construct padded subsets of W.. Maybe you can help with that .

Comment: @nour I'm still not sure what padded subsets are. What you are describing is that $W$ spans your space.

Comment: Yes ! every element in a padded subset can be obtained as a linear combination of other elements in the same subset.

Comment: @nour Ok, then a padded subset of $W$ is any set $S$ contained in $\operatorname{span} \{u_1, \ldots, u_m\}$. Elements of $S$ will be of the form $\alpha_1u_1 + \ldots + \alpha_mu_m$ for some scalars $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_m$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70960/discussion-between-nour-and-mechanodroid).

Answer (score 2):

Note that:

$$u_{1}-u_{2},u_{2}-u_{3},...,u_{m-1}-u_{m},u_{m}-u_{1}$$

are linerly dependent by

$$u_{1},u_{2},...,u_{m}$$

thus the number of linearly independant elements of $W$ is equal to the number of linearly independant elements among $u_{1},u_{2},...,u_{m}$.